# Word2Vec Too Many Values to Unpack Error

Tags: python, pandas, word2vec

I am trying to turn a word2vec result into a pretty dataframe.

`df_word2vec_tfidf` is my doc2vec model, `tfidf_feature_names` is my list of keys I am using to grab similar words.

```
def get_word_table(table, key, sim_key='similarity', show_sim = True):
    if show_sim == True:
        return pd.DataFrame(table, columns=[key, sim_key])
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame(table, columns=[key, sim_key])[key]

keys = [tfidf_feature_names];
tables = [];
for key in keys:
    tables.append(get_word_table(word2vec_model.wv.similar_by_word(key), key, show_sim=False))

pd.concat(tables, axis=1)
```

I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).

Any ideas on whats going on here??

Comment: Can you include the full error message so we know where in your code the error is occurring?

Answer (score 1):

Your keys should be in the following format, is it?

```
def get_word_table(table, key, sim_key='similarity', show_sim = True):
    if show_sim == True:
        return pd.DataFrame(table, columns=[key, sim_key])
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame(table, columns=[key, sim_key])[key]



keys = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'wordn']
tables = [];
for key in keys:
    tables.append(get_word_table(model.wv.similar_by_word(key), key, show_sim=False))
pd.concat(tables, axis=1)
```

So your keys should be `keys = tfidf_feature_names`